# Cannot start iPhone Simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, xcode6.3.1

I have Unity 5.0.2p1 Personal and Xcode Version 6.3.1 (6D1002).

Here are some steps for anyone hoping to reproduce the problem:

1. A new blank Unity project
2. IOS Player Settings > SDK Version : Simulator SDK
3. Build and Run produces this when app is launched in simulator:

> Warning: Error creating LLDB target at path '/Users/...(user
> name).../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-couukthirzleocbdfmbmdpjhxrtr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ProductName.app'-
> using an empty LLDB target which can cause slow memory reads from
> remote devices.
>
> dyld: Symbol not found: __ZN5metal16g_CurrentEncoderE
>
> Referenced from: /Users/...(user name).../Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/530A44CB-5978-4926-9E91-E9DBD5BFB105/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/07612A5C-659D-4C04-ACD3-D211D2830E17/ProductName.app/ProductName
>
> Expected in: flat namespace
>
> in /Users/...(user name).../Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/530A44CB-5978-4926-9E91-E9DBD5BFB105/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/07612A5C-659D-4C04-ACD3-D211D2830E17/ProductName.app/ProductName

Then, if you select Standard Architecture in Xcode Build Settings and build and run again it produces this:

> dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _UnityRegisterProInterface
>
> Referenced from: /Users/...(user name).../Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/530A44CB-5978-4926-9E91-E9DBD5BFB105/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/444E88D1-3B5D-46FA-A143-B8634F56398E/ProductName.app/ProductName
>
> Expected in: flat namespace
>
> dyld: Symbol not found: _UnityRegisterProInterface
>
> Referenced from: /Users/...(user name).../Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/530A44CB-5978-4926-9E91-E9DBD5BFB105/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/444E88D1-3B5D-46FA-A143-B8634F56398E/ProductName.app/ProductName
>
> Expected in: flat namespace
>
> (lldb)

The same results occur for various settings in Unity iOS Player Settings:

- Scripting Backend: Mono (2.0) / IL2CPP
- Architecture: ARMv7 / ARM64 / Universal
- Target iOS version: 6.0 / 8.1
- Graphics API: Automatic / Open GL ES 2.0 / Open GL ES 3.0 / Metal

Also get the same results using Xcode Build Settings:

- Base SDK: iphonesimulator (SDK not found) / Standard architectures (armv7, arm64) - $(ARCHS_STANDARD)
- Supported Platforms: iphonesimulator / iOS
- iOS Deployment Target: iOS 6.0 / iOS 8.1 / iOS 8.3

Any hints are very appreciated.

Comment: It looks like this is a bug in 5.0.2p1 on the Unity side. We have a fix that should be out in a later patch release.

Comment: Which Unity version shall I install to creating ios-apps and testing it on the iphone-simulator?. Unity 5.0.x version got the same error and the app can not started on the iphone-simulator..

I use Xcode 6.3.2.

Comment: I'm not sure yet which version will have this fix. It will be after 5.0.2p1, certainly. Likely in the next patch release or two.

Comment: Just updated to 5.0.2p4 -- still having this issue. Unity has not responded to my bug report yet (been 9 days).

Answer (score 0):

This is solved in Patch Release 5.1.0p1 : https://unity3d.com/unity/qa/patch-releases

Check out the Release Notes : (696798) - iOS: Fixed simulator crashing on startup due to "Symbol not found: __ZN5metal16g_CurrentEncoderE".